# Relationship between intensity and sound level

Tags: noise, intensity

So I know that for every tenfold increase in intensity, the sound level increases by 10 dB. So if the intensity is increased by a factor of 100000, the sound level increases by 50 dB. I also know that it comes from the equation below and generally if you want to know how much the sound level is increased by some factor, you can use this equation

βf = βi + 10dB[log(If/Ii)]

But I thought what if the sound level changes by some factor? I tried using this equation and kept hitting dead ends. I’m just curious if there is a proof for this. I know I can just plug in numbers and see how much the intensity changes

Also I saw something that confused me.  According to my book “increasing the sound level by factor of 10 increases the perception of loudness by a factor of two”. I thought the sound level was how we quantify perception of loudness. I feel like I’m missing something here.[image: Edit]

Comment: So,  what is your first question? How do you go to a dead end?

Comment: @nasu the math gets exceedingly complicated. I just posted a picture as an edit.

Comment: @nasu also it’s just the b2/b1 part. The other part was something else

Comment: Don't you mean $40\,\textrm{dB}$ in the first paragraph, since $10,000=10^4$?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I thought I added another zero, but yes if it increased by 10K it would be 10^4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sound level increases by $\Delta \beta=\beta_f-\beta_i$, then

$$\frac{I_f}{I_i}=10^{\Delta \beta / 10}$$

Similarly, if the sound level increases by a factor $C=\beta_f/\beta_i$, then

$$\frac{I_f}{I_i}=10^{\frac{\beta_i(C-1)}{10}}$$

Please let me know if I should explain the algebra that I used to derive these.

---

### Edit

$$\begin{align}
\beta_f-\beta_i&=10\log\left(\frac{I_f}{I_i}\right)\\
\implies \frac{\beta_f}{\beta_i}-1&= \frac{10}{\beta_i} \log\left(\frac{I_f}{I_i}\right)\\
\implies \frac{\beta_i}{10}\left(C-1\right)&=\log\left(\frac{I_f}{I_i}\right)\\
\implies 10^{\frac{\beta_i}{10}\left(C-1\right)}&=\frac{I_f}{I_i}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes please. I understood the first equation because that’s how I understood the relationship but I’m not sure how Δβ becomes C-1.

Comment: @Ibby I edited my answer to include the derivation. By the way, I had made a typo in my second equation with $C-1$. I had forgotten to type a factor of $\beta_i$. Now it's included.

Comment: Ok great. Thank you so much